# Reading from nativeptr<T> in System.Numerics.Vector<T> chunks

Tags: .net, pointers, f#, unmanaged, simd

In F# we can dereference a pointer pointing to a value of type `'a` like so

```
open FSharp.NativeInterop
let x = NativePtr.read p
```

where `p` is a `nativeptr<'a>`.

Now assume that this pointer points to an array of `'a` values and that we want to process this array using SIMD via `System.Numerics.Vector<_>`. For that we would have to load *n* consecutive `'a` values into a `Vector<'a>` struct. For .NET/managed arrays this can be achieved by using the appropriate `Vector<_>` constructor. But unfortunately, all we have is a *pointer* (which, in fact, points to the unmanaged heap, in this particular case), so we can't use one of the existing constructor overloads.

So, what about simply re-interpreting `p` as a `nativeptr<Vector<'a>>`?

```
let inline cast<'T, 'U when 'U : unmanaged and 'T: unmanaged> (ptr: nativeptr<'T>) =
    ptr |> NativePtr.toNativeInt |> NativePtr.ofNativeInt<'U>

let v = p |> NativePtr.cast<'a, Vector<'a>> |> NativePtr.read
```

Sadly, this doesn't workt, because the type parameter of `nativeptr` has to fulfill the `unmanaged` constraint - which `Vector<_>`, [as a generic data type](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/generics/constraints), does not.

Now, one way to work around this issue is to use C# in combination with [NativeInterop](https://bitbucket.org/frank_niemeyer/nativeinterop), because the `unmanaged` constraint is not enforced by the C# compiler. Yet, I'd really like to stay in F#.

Is there any hope this could work **efficiently** from F#? Or is the only option to wait that `Vector<_>` is extended with a constructor that supports loading from pointers?

Comment: You can't "reinterpret" raw memory as an object of a specific type, even if C# compiler would let you. This is not C language. CLR types are more than merely compile-time constructs, they have runtime representation as well. That `unmanaged` constraint is there for a reason.

Comment: [Of course I can](https://gist.github.com/FrankNiemeyer/38f376e78fdc53cf3246deb7822b959a) (and, as I've described, the C# compiler does "let me", but not the F# comp.). `Vector<T>` is blittable (`T` is always unmanaged as only primitive types are supported) and boils down to 128 (SSE) or 256 bit (AVX) SIMD strides in memory, the only way to implement efficient SIMD intrinsics on top of it.

Comment: I don't think your program does what you think it does. That `IntPtr.Read` extension method does not "reinterpret" the memory as `Vector<double>`, it actually copies several bytes to a new place.

Comment: `p.Read<Vector<double>>` copies 16 (SSE) or 32 (AVX) bytes onto the stack, which is then treated as a Vector<double>. It does exactly what it should.

Comment: @Fyodor Btw. it seems like you are missing the point of my question. It's *not* about "converting" the blob of memory to some other type e.g. a managed array of Vector<T> or something like that. Not at all.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be way around this issue in F# itself. I therefore implemented a little wrapper in C# that basically simply forwards to [`NativeInteropEx.NativePtr`](https://bitbucket.org/frank_niemeyer/nativeinterop), but strips off the `unmanaged` constraint unknown to the C# compiler:

```
using NativeInteropEx;
using System.Numerics;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public struct VectorView<T> where T: struct
{
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static Vector<T> Get(IntPtr p, int idx) {
        return p.Get<Vector<T>>(idx);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static Vector<T> Get(IntPtr p, long idx) {
        return p.Get<Vector<T>>(idx);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void Set(IntPtr p, int idx, Vector<T> value) {
        p.Set(idx, value);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void Set(IntPtr p, long idx, Vector<T> value) {
        p.Set(idx, value);
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static Vector<T> Read(IntPtr p) {
        return p.Read<Vector<T>>();
    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static void Write(IntPtr p, Vector<T> value) {
        p.Write(value);
    }
}
```

Using this intermediate layer, we can now dereference a `nativeptr<'T>` as a `Vector<'T>` from within F#:

```
# baseAddress: nativeptr<'T> when 'T: unmanaged
# idx: int64
let v = VectorView<'T>.Get(baseAddress, idx)
# v: Vector<'T> of Vector<'T>.Count 'T values starting with baseAddress + sizeof<'T> * idx
```

Comment: To clarify for potential users: This does precisely the same thing as the unsafe (private) [`System.Numerics.Vector<T>` constructor](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/System.Numerics.Vectors/src/System/Numerics/Vector.cs#L619) creating a `Vector<T>` from a `void*` and an offset. Only difference is that we don't need explicit type switches because we can use `NativeInterop` for generic pointer operations.